# Java error: class, interface or enum expected? the pointer points at import java.util.Scanner;?

Tags: java

```
class Xyz {
    public void simpleMessage(String name)
    {
        System.out.println("Hello " + name);
    }
}
```

Here is Abc class:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Abc {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        Xyz tob = new Xyz();
        System.out.println("Hello enter you name : ");
        String name = in.nextLine();
        tob.simpleMessage(name);
    }
}
```

Comment: Move the `import` to the top of the file. Please go through [basic tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/).

Comment: Format your code using the format code button. From attempting to decipher this somewhat unreadable block I suggest that you should read a [basic tutorial on Java syntax](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classes.html).

Comment: move Import statement to top of file and make sure file name is Abc.java

Comment: @MarounMaroun - Although you are right, I think he will get a *misplaced Construct* error in that case..

Comment: Should be `Xyz` a inner class?

Comment: This looks like two separate files posted as a single one... if it isn't then this has already been solved in comments.

Comment: @TheLostMind OP's formatting is confusing but I think all statements inside methods which are inside classes.

Comment: thank u guys but none of this helped :(

Comment: Guys can some one explain me how to use multiple classes in one programe.I am new to java but i understood evry concept except this

Comment: You can have more than one class in one `.java` file as long as at most one class is `public` and the `.java` file is named after the `public class`. But the `import` statements must be placed *before* any class definition. Or you simply create a single `.java` file for each class having the name of the class and the `.java` ending. Still, `import` statements must be placed before any class definition but for the single class `Abc` you did it right. So after moving the class `Xyz` into its own file `Xyz.java` there should be no problem anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Looks Like you have pasted 2 files in same code.

change the ***ist class to public or put it in same package***.

**ist class must be compiled before the second class.**

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the import statement at the top of the file before defining class xyz.